# Generate 3d point out of a solid object

Tags: 3d, geometry

I have worked with 2D and little bit of OpenCV and now wants to work with 3D object.  So first of all I want to know how to generate 3d point out of solid object, for saying I have a duck object and I want a 3d point, how can i generate 3d point?

I have done R&D on Google and found that point could be generated from laser, kinnect sensor etc and also there are a library called Point Cloud and CGAL also available, but that comes into the picture after I have some points.

So First of All I want to know how to generate 3d points? It it can be generated by laser, could you please guide me in right direction for setting up methodology for get data using laser source or any other medium.

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There's another, cheaper method for generating a set of points from a 3D object, and it's called [structure-from-motion](http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/).

Very briefly, it takes as input, a collection of photographs of a 3D object (or a scene) and figures out correspondences (where the same visual features occur in different images) and using multiple such correspondences, estimates the location of those feature points in 3D.

There are a bunch of [opensource projects](http://www.findbestopensource.com/tagged/reconstruction) dealing with reconstruction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the even cheaper way to get a duck 3d object is to model it yourself using standard 3d softwares though ;) In fact, more than points, the entire geometry (including triangles/connectivity) is often needed. And sfm and lasers don't provide that natively (they give a set of points, indeed... but then, you have to generate the mesh)

Comment: @WhitAngl: You certainly make a valid point. I've done a bit of work in this area myself. Unfortunately, there are no fully-automated techniques for meshing an arbitrary set of points. Suresh seems to only want the points, though (if I read his question correctly). Or we may have an "XY problem" :)

Comment: Hi Rahul, This link will definitely will help. WintAngl, Yes laser and sfm gives the point but how to get those points and generate mesh out of the points? I know this both things are two different, but I want to generate 3d points and make a mesh out of the points. Which library will suits the best to generate mesh?